# Strange behavior in Ansible when using `to_nice_yaml` filter

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have an ansible playbook, which first initializes a fact using `set_fact`, and then a task that consumes the fact and generates a YAML file from it.

The playbook looks like this

```
- name: Test yaml output
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks:
     - name: set config
       set_fact:
         config:
            A12345: '00000000000000000000000087895423'
            A12352: '00000000000000000000000087565857'
            A12353: '00000000000000000000000031200527'
     - name : gen yaml file
       copy:
           dest: "a.yaml"
           content: "{{ config | to_nice_yaml }}"
```

**Actual Output**

When I run the playbook, the output in a.yaml is

```
A12345: 00000000000000000000000087895423
A12352: 00000000000000000000000087565857
A12353: '00000000000000000000000031200527'
```

Notice only the last line has the value in quotes

**Expected Output**

The expected output is

```
A12345: '00000000000000000000000087895423'
A12352: '00000000000000000000000087565857'
A12353: '00000000000000000000000031200527'
```

All values should be quoted.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why only the last line has the value printed in single-quotes.

I've tried this with Ansible version 2.7.7, and version 2.11.12, both running against Python 3.7.3. The behavior is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `031200527` is [an octal number](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.1/#id2761292), whereas `087895423` is not, thus, the octal scalar needs quoting but the other values do not because the leading zeros are interpreted in yaml exactly the same way `00hello` would be -- just the ascii `0` followed by other ascii characters

If it really bothers you that much, and having quoted scalars is obligatory for some reason, `to_nice_yaml` accepts the same kwargs [as does `pyyaml.dump`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#cb67):

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: '{{ thing | to_nice_yaml(default_style=quote) }}'
  vars:
    quote: "'"
    thing:
      A1234: '008123'
      A2345: '003123'
```

which in this case will also quote the keys, but unconditionally quotes the scalars

Comment: Thanks. That explains a lot. My concern was the the output wasn't valid yaml.

Comment: @RandomPerson The output in your example question is definitely valid yaml. Quotes are not mandatory for strings. See for example [learning yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)