# Ansible Strange Type Conversion When Using Inventory Files vs. Setting Vars on command line

Tags: unicode, ansible, yaml

When using Ansible, I've observed some strange behavior that I can't understand. Hopefully someone on here can help.

If I define a playbook like so:

```
---
  - hosts: localhost
    tasks:
        - debug: msg="{{ myvar }}"
```

and create an extra-vars file like so:

```
myvar: 053507662074
```

When I execute the playbook like so:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @extra_var_file.yml
```

The output is:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": 5857305660
}
```

Notice how 053507662074 gets converted to 5857305660

If I set the variable on the command line like:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "myvar=053507662074"
```

the output is as expected:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "053507662074"
}
```

** Can anyone help explain what's going on here? I used "type_debug" and the cmdline returns type of "unicode" whereas using an extra-vars file it returns type "int". Is there something I'm missing here like hex/oct conversion? **

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi whynotnow welcome to SO. This must be the week for [telling people about octal in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72371849/strange-behavior-in-ansible-when-using-to-nice-yaml-filter/72372364#72372364) but if you quote the scalar in your .yml you'll get the same outcome in both paths

Comment: thanks @mdaniel, that was it exactly. I've been using Ansible & YAML for about 6 years now and it's the first time I've encountered this. You learn something new everyday :)

Comment: Then feel free to add the way you fixed it and accept your own answer, as covered in the https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer section. I'm glad it was something simple